# shared_ptr and shared_array allocate memory for reference counter

Tags: c++, boost, stl

After profiling my application I found out that there are far too many `malloc`s. I was surprised that `shared_ptr` and `shared_array` allocated memory for reference counts. Besides that an object which encapsulates reference counts contain two counts `uses_count` and `weak_count` as well as a pointer to the virtual table. To me this seems like overkill when I only need a simple reference counting class. Is there any way to tweak `shared_ptr` and `shared_array` to implement a simpler scheme? Without additional call to `malloc` and only with one counter: `uses_count`. Or maybe there's a simpler class somewhere in STL or Boost?

Comment: Use `make_shared`.

Comment: Which is precisely the reason I don't use shared_ptr etc. Especially, because this means that I would not be allowed to make a smart pointer from a plain pointer, forcing me to use an extra level of indirection etc. The only clean way for reference counting I know is: implement it in a base class and derive everything from it. Add a smart pointer template, and you have something usable without any subtle catches. The STL approach is too much of a fix to be sensible IMHO.

Comment: @cmaster the implementation in a base class has been done for you already: `boost::intrusive_ptr` ;-)

Comment: What I'd like to know is why the ref counter is still alocated in the default constructor. This should get allocated only at reset, or when constructed from pointer. This looses a lot of perf. I feel this is purely for the sake of "ifless programming" or said differently "special cases are not special enough to break the rules" but this is bad here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `boost::make_shared`, the function will allocate the memory for both the ref counter and the object in one single call to `new`. 
The additional counter for weak refereces should not be a big problem, since its only an additional 4 or 8 bytes that won't hurt.
If profiling shows that `shared_ptr`'s implementation still is a bottleneck for your application, consider to use `boost::intrusive_ptr`. Also look for passing the shared_ptrs by reference rather than by value or pass them by moving them if a copy is needed. Of course, if you can use `unique_ptr` you should prefer those over `shared_ptr`s

Comment: Thank you! intrusive_ptr is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    shared_ptr<A> sp( new A(), A_Deleter(), My_allocator<A>() );

    template <typename T> 
    class My_allocator 
    { 
        ...
        T * allocate(const size_t n) const {
            return singleton_pool<T,sizeof(T)>::malloc();
        }
        ....
    };
```

I think you complain about memory usage problem. I found std allocator could solve it;